# How to intercept HttpServletRequest with Spring MVC Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring/Jackson to auto convert json to POJOs. All is working fine, except when I'm doing my header authentication (using a filter). I've been using request.getContentLength() to get the length of the json string.

This worked fine, until the json contains a diacritic character. Where the content length then reports to be one character longer. So obviously I have to get the actual json body. This is proving difficult as calling request.getInputStream causes Jackson to fail as the input stream is already closed. Same for getReader.

So, I've done as outlined in this blog: http://natch3z.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html

Which works but doesn't properly encode to UTF-8. So I replaced this line:

```
  bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

to:

```
  bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Which displays the correct json in my log, but I get this error when jackson tries to convert to a pojo:

```
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x9f
```

I'm not sure how to get this working, if anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to know in advance the length of the json string in your filter? Just wondering if it's possible to bypass the actual problem...

Comment: Yeah, I needed the json length.. I've posted the solution below. Credit to the blog as it works with just a minor adjustment that I showed.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out:

I replaced this line:

```
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
```

with this:

```
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I should have realized sooner, but this may help someone else with a similar issue.